# Why do users with high reputation just not answer the question but instead ask why a question is being asked?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

This is not about my question, I am still new to Python, so there is a huge knowledge gap for me to answer any question clearly, [but this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053178/copying-to-pre-allocated-list-slower-than-append-which-seems-counter-intuitive) asked by a different user I have no relation with [received a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053178/copying-to-pre-allocated-list-slower-than-append-which-seems-counter-intuitive#comment122042769_69053178) that says

> Are you actually trying to solve the problem of copying quickly? Or
> are you just wondering about these two specific approaches for a
> specific reason? If so, for what reason? If you just want an efficient
> copy, what's wrong with data.copy()? Or data[:]? Also, you are aware
> that this kind of thing is implementation-specific, right?

OP very well states this is in the first line of the post:

> This question has nothing to do with how to copy one list to another.
> It's about performance.

This is not the only post or the only user (I am not targeting the user who made that comment) that has such comments. I use this site to learn things like what the OP has asked, but comments like that is not valuable for users like us.

Why can not they just answer or point towards resources that answer the question instead of leaving comments that question the question?

The question has been answered by the same user that commented after I posted this question, but my concern still stands.

Comment: There is a difference between what the OP **wants** and what they **need**. Asking questions in the comments narrows that down.

Comment: I agree with that, and I am guessing asking question in comments avoids "XY" problems, but to my understanding, questions like this can not be inferred in any other way, it states its all about performance @Paulie_D

Comment: @yivi why would you go and edit my old questions on stackoverlfow? which have very well been answered and marked accepted

Comment: *"OP very well states this is in the first line of the post"* - That quote you've provided doesn't appear to answer the questions in the comment at all.

Comment: That a question is answered and/or accepted is not particularly regarding improving it with edits. I made minute improvements to a couple of your questions; hopefully helping you avoiding similar mistakes in the future. Regarding my previous comment, it’s meant to illustrate by example a problem with this question here. I’m sorry that the example seems to be lost on you. Good luck in the future. Bye!

Comment: “Why can not just they answer or point towards resources that answer the question instead of leaving comments that question the question?” - If you want useless answers that are nothing but a signpost to another website Quora is the Q&A community for you.  Quora of course is trash.  To put it simply, answers that simply point to resources without any explanation, are low quality and unhelpful. Understanding a question, requires understanding what is being attempted, which sometimes means asking what is being asked. If a comment is rude just flag it for a moderator to deal with

Comment: *"This comment to this question does exactly what I just explained"* not at all. You've made baseless sweeping comments about "high rep" users, so to counter point Yivi is demonstrating a baseless accusation that "low rep" users are just at as bad. In truth, the reputation has little to do with it though.

Comment: @Larnu just for the record, I did not mean “low rep users are just as bad”, but simply pointing the absurdity of this kind of generalization.

Answer (score 28):

If I'm going to spend 15 minutes of my free time in writing an awesome answer I better make sure I 100% understand what the OP is asking.

Alternatively, a well-formed comment might reveal I'm dealing with a proper duplicate and can instead hunt down the best one to duplicate close vote against that target, helping the OP with proven answers and future visitors with the same question finding the dupe as well.

Whether a user is high reputation or not is not relevant. Anyone that feels a clarification is needed before they can write a high-quality, well-received answer should do so. You might see these comments more often from high-rep users either because they have previously answered questions that turned out to have different needs or they have seen the issue as described but are now looking for the right tweak that applies here. But a subject matter expert that created an account 6 days ago might raise a similar comment.

For that specific question: Performance is tricky as it is unlikely anyone except the OP can reliably tell if a given answer would indeed improve the performance. Context, toolstack, runtime, versions etc matter in this category of questions. Making sure you provide an answer that addresses the issue the OP brought up does often need way more info than is supplied initially.

In general: We strive to create and curate a body of knowledge in the form of Questions and Answers, not Questions and a best guess. That is why those users that can answer a question tend to verify their own thoughts / concerns in a comment before they start blurting things in the answer box.

Comment: Minor nitpick: *"Whether a user is high reputation or not is not relevant."* Depending on your definition of 'high' it may be relevant, since you need 50 points to be able to comment on other people's posts. :)

Comment: @user000001 I would be surprised if anybody considered 50 reputation “high” :)